# Determinant of an endomorphism (Proof)

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I Need to prove That for every a there is an endomorphism phi such that det(phi)=a.

I habe no idea how to do this. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you quote the exact question? Because that's false in a trivial vector space.

Comment: The exact question says: Proof: For every a (element of K) there is an endomorphism phi: V->V with det(phi)=a.

Comment: Okay, then does the problem set define what it means by V, somewhere above that?

Comment: @Chris is the determinant defined for an endomorphism on the trivial vector space?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hmm, I had assumed it must be defined, and to equal $1$. But none of the three linear algebra textbooks I checked do define it!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking of a $n$ dimensional vector space that is non trivial.

If $a \in \mathbb{K}$, and $\mathbb{K}^n = \mathrm{vect}(e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n)$, what can you say about the determinent of the endomorphism $u$ defined by
\begin{align}
u(e_1) &= a\cdot e_1 \\
u(e_j) &= e_j, j>1
\end{align}
?

Comment: The determinant is equal to a*1^(j-1)=a.

Answer (score 0):

If we are in a $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbf F$, consider the endomorphism $\phi : V \to V$ such that, in some basis, its matrix representation is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: So we will always find det(phi)=a, right?

Comment: Yes, the determinant of $\phi$ is independent of the choice of the basis.